# Big O of functionF

Tags: java, recursion, runtime, big-o, complexity-theory

```
static void functionF(int n) {
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
             functionF(n-1);
     }
}
```

I've calculated that:

if n = 2, the function gets called 4 more times. If n = 3, it gets called 15 more times. If n = 4, it gets called 64 more times. I am trying to work out a big O time complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a complexity pov, it takes factorial time to complete -> O(n!)

Because every step, would run the amount of times specified in the last step.
And note the diference between your function and:

```java
function alpha(n){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; n++){
        //Do some stuff
        alpha(i)
    }
}
```

or

```java
function alpha(n){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            // Do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

The first one i can't really guess its time, buts lower than O(n!)
The second one is the simple O(n²), which in any real situacion runs faster than O(n!)

Answer (score 1):

Tested this function by incrementing a public static variable every time the function is called. You could do this in the future if you want to check how many times something is done.

The pattern beginning with (1, 4, 15, 64, 325, ...) is:

```
a(n) = n(a(n-1) + 1)
```

or

```
a(n) = n(a(n-1)) + n
```

That's such an odd function because of the recursive aspect of it. However, it's accurate. You could have searched this pattern up from the numbers you provided, as well.